# OpenWRT port-forwarding doesn't work for me

Tags: networking, router, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward a few ports to a server that I run, mainly port 80, 443, and 22. Right now I'm just trying to get a single port forward working but no dice. The firewall on the server accepts the ports, but I still can't connect to the server from outside my network, even if I disable the firewall and SELinux. Ironically mywebserver.com works inside my network, but not outside my network.

I had this working before I flashed OpenWRT so I know things are set up properly on the server, the only change is OpenWRT so I must be doing something wrong.

Firewall settings are here: https://pastebin.com/hzkJYep3

Not sure what else you might need but just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Install tcpdump and see traffic on out interface and on br-lan to see what exactly going there.

```
opkg update
opkg install tcpdump
```

If its firewall config issue you will not see requests on br-lan.
If you see requests and response from server on br-lan but dont see reply on external interface - its mean NAT not enabled or not allowed forwarding from lan zone to wan.